# Найти последний файл в каталоге. С++

Tags: c++, файлы, файловая-система, c++17

Подскажите более оптимальный вариант поиска последнего файла в каталоге.
Файлы в каталоге имеют расширение `.dat` и пронумерованы от 1. То есть такой вид:

```
1.dat 
2.dat
3.dat
```

Вот, что у меня есть:

```
const file_system::path work_dir = file_system::current_path();
string tmp;

for (const auto& entry : file_system::directory_iterator(work_dir))
{
    tmp = entry.path().filename().string();
}
```

Ну и в итоге `tmp` будет содержать идентификатор последнего файла, но здесь линейный поиск, а возможно это сделать быстрее? С учетом того, что файлы могут редактироваться.

Comment: Может как-то поставить итератор сразу на конец каталога и взять оттуда идентификатор файла?

Comment: вообще формально порядок итерирования для file_system::directory_iterator не определен (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator), так что вам надо пройтись по всем вхождениям, сложить их имена в вектор (или куда-то еще) и отсортировать его вручную

Comment: Вам надо определиться, что такое "последний" файл. С учётом того, что используются числовые имена, даже если предположить сортировку по имени - возможна как сортировка по значению, так и лексикографическая, а они дадут разные результаты...

Comment: @goldstar_labs если нет других вариантов, то лучше я останусь на этом, потому что делать vector(или любой другой контейнер), потом его сортировать точно будет гораздо менее производительнее, чем я буду просто итерироваться по каталогу.

Comment: @Akina последний файл - файл, который находится последним в списке.

Comment: порядок итерирования не определен и ваше решение не рабочее в общем случае

Comment: @goldstar_labs а можете привести вариант, в котором оно сломается? С учетом того, что в это каталоге будут находиться только файлы, пронумерованные от 1 и далее с расширением .dat.

Comment: *а можете привести вариант, в котором оно сломается?* Лехко. Поместите в каталог файлы от 1.dat до 10.dat. Сравните порядок вывода в окне Explorer (последним будет 10.dat) и в консоли (последним будет 9.dat).

Comment: @Akina сейчас протестил на нескольких директориях и все работет как нужно - возвращает именно последний идентификатор. Даже если бы в ходе выяснилось, что возвращает на 1 больше или меньше - с этого всегда есть выход. А с учетом того, что мне выводить эту информацию никуда не нужно, то данные, полученные этим методом, являются корректным. Но я надеялся, что можно как-то поставить итератор сразу на последний файл и разыменовывать его.

Comment: @Akina, беру слова назад. Действительно ломается.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что файлы пронумерованы от 1 и по порядку. В общем случае, если это условие сохраняется, то имя последнего файла равно числу файлов в каталоге. В этом случае и искать ничего не нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С учетом всех замечаний, что были выражены в комментах, пришел к варианту, что самый оптимальный способ для решения моей задачи(найти последнее число, чтобы использовать его для создания следующего файла):

```
auto dir_iter = fs::directory_iterator(id_file_cat_name);

int file_count = count_if(begin(dir_iter), end(dir_iter), [](auto& entry) {return entry.is_regular_file(); });
```

Comment: пожалуйста формулируйте задачу более полно в следующий раз, а то в вопросе у вас про последний файл в каталоге, а по факту вам просто надо создать новый файл с уникальным именем-номером

Comment: @goldstar_labs просто в начале думал делать одним способом, а потом перешёл на этот уже.

Comment: а когда файлов в каталоге будет много, программа будет немного тупить. Когда будет больше - "пусть пользователи подождут":) Как по мне, то  проще этот номер сохранить в конфиге. А при старте просто сверить.